# Luxemburg norm as argument of Young's function: $\Phi\left(\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\Phi}}\right)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, orlicz-spaces

Let $\Phi$ be a *Youngs's function*, i.e.
$$ \Phi(t) = \int_0^t \varphi(s) \,\mathrm d s$$
for some $\varphi$ satifying

1. $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty]$ is increasing
2. $\varphi$ is lower semi continuous
3. $\varphi(0) = 0$
4. $\varphi$ is neither identically zero nor identically infinite

and define the *Luxemburg norm* of $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ as
$$ \lVert f \rVert_{L^{\Phi}} := \inf \left\{\gamma\,\middle|\,\gamma>0,\,\int_{\Omega} \Phi\left(\frac {\lvert f(x)\rvert}{\gamma} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq 1\right\}.$$

---

> **Question**: What can we say about $\Phi\left(\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\Phi}}\right)$? In particular, I'd like to know, if
>   $$\Phi\left(\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\Phi}}\right) \leq C \int_{\Omega}\Phi(\lvert f(x)\rvert) \,\mathrm d x$$
>   holds for some $C$
>   independent of $f$.

Any idea or hint for a reference is welcome!

---

**Notes**:

- The above inequality trivially holds for $\Phi(t) = t^p$, where $p>1$
- Maybe it's appropriate to consider this question in the more general framework of Musielak-Orlicz spaces. However, e.g. in [Lebesgue and Sobolev Spaces with Variable Exponents](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~diening/archive/book.pdf) I was unable to find an appropriate result.
- Since there has been no response yet, I also asked the question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333888/luxemburg-norm-as-argument-of-youngs-function-phi-left-lvert-f-rvert-l).

Comment: Do you mean to write $\inf \{\int_\Omega\dots | \gamma>0\}$ instead of $\inf \{\gamma>0 | \int_\Omega\dots \}$? The notation is not clear to me

Comment: No, it's supposed to be the $\inf$ over the $\gamma$. Maybe $\inf\{\gamma\,|\,\gamma>0,\,\int_{\Omega}...\}$ is better? Ah, and I forgot the $\leq 1$ … Sorry!

Comment: A counterexample has been given by @harfe on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/333925/141833).